# Aliases in nginx/apache vs CNAME record?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, cname-record, configuration, alias

In one of my nginx `sites-available` configuration file, I can specify a server name alias, like so:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

If I had an Apache server, I can do something similar with `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

I have also specified a `CNAME` record in my zone file:

```
www.example.com. 1800 IN CNAME example.com.
```

I want `www.example.com` and `example.com` to server the same content. Since I have a `CNAME` record, all `www.example.com` will be pointed to `example.com` anyways, so there's no need for the alias. The argument can also be turned on its head to say the `CNAME` record is not needed.

**Is the alias in my web server (nginx or Apache) and the CNAME record redundant?** If so, should I get rid of one of them? And if so, which one?

Comment: It is best to always have one domain version in use (either www.example.com or example.com), and then have a permanent redirect from the other version to the main version. This way you won't be flagged with duplicate content penalties from search engines.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks for the tip! I was literally reading about it as you posted the comment! 301 Redirect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the CNAME, you would need an A record for the www-subdomain instead, otherwise DNS resolution for `www.example.com` won't work and the request won't reach your server.

You will also need the `ServerAlias`, because even when using CNAME, the host header in the HTTP request won't change, so it will still be `www.example.com` and you need to tell Apache/nginx which vhost should serve this request.

So nothing's redundant here. The only advantage of using a CNAME for `www.example.com` instead of an A record is that when your IP changes, you will only have to change the A record for `example.com` . When using A records, you would have to change them both.

Comment: Had to read it a few times to realize it is a fantastic answer, cleared everything up for me! `CNAME` record to point the HTTP packet to the correct IP address, but the host header within this HTTP packet still wouldn't change and still needs an alias from the web server virtual host/server block configuration.